# How to start a computer with backup of another computer?

Tags: windows-7, backup

I have a notebook with core2duo processor and I have installed Windows 7 (64bit) on it. Now I want to have the backup of my C drive and want to run my Desktop with that backup? But it is not running. Why?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/faq

Comment: This is off-topic.  Please consider posting this on http://serverfault.com/

Comment: So you think that copying the C: drive of a machine to a C: drive of a totally different machine (hardware, ram, processor, network, display drivers, usb ports, bus architecture, etc etc etc.) should work? Ok, it's off-topic here.

Comment: lol of people trying to answer this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When the OS is installed it can choose to put different types of files for different machines where it is being installed, including different drivers. When you try to boot it can fail because it ha not been installed for that particular hardware. You need to re-install the windows for the new machine over the backup C: installation. You can keep the other files, but just re-install over the existing installation, or even install somewhere else and then just read the files. But it is highly unlikely a windows install from one machine will boot on another machine.

Comment: Not to mention that unless you have purchased another license (or a license that allows this such as a corporate site license) it is illegal.

Answer (score 0):

The hardware on the two computers is different, the files that were installed on the laptop to run Windows7 are not the ones the desktop computer needs to start up successfully.

Comment: So what is the solution? If my notebook is dead today and even if the hard disk is working, how can I get my data back? By data I don't mean normal files. I have installed too many software with too many settings and with too many entries. Does that mean, I have lost everything?

Comment: @ShujaAhmed - Acronis True Image 2013 Plus can restore an image of your hdd to another computer.  Using a program design to get rid of the driver errors is advised it doesn't HAVE to be True Image.